# API Call on “wpcf7_form_tag_data_option” causing slow loading

Tags: wordpress, api, contact-form-7, wordpress-hook

I'm loading some fields of my form dynamically using the **"wpcf7_form_tag_data_option"** filter, full code below.

From this filter I call a function that does an API call to get the list of fields to be displayed on a radio buttons. It all works well, but the function executes when the page loads, which causes a delay, especially if the API is slow to respond.

How could I change my code so the functions loads only after the page is loaded?
Or could I have it work asynchronously so it doesn't interfere with the page load?

Here is how the data is called on my form:
`[radio class_list_1_1 data:class_list]`

And then my functions.php - filter function

```
function display_class_list($n, $options, $args) {
  if (in_array('class_list', $options)){
    $class_list = get_class_list(); 
    return $class_list; 
  }
  return $n;
}
```

Comment: What is `get_class_list()` ?

Comment: Hi Howard, get_class_list() is the function containing the API call which return a json from which I get the list of classes available for booking. This is basically where the delay come from but I'm not sure what to do in order to wait for the page to be fully loaded before to execute the function.

Comment: You could try triggering the get_class_list on page load and storing it in a transient

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I had a look at the wordpress doc as I never heard of transients, however I see that it's limited to 172 characters so that won't work for me. 

Following your idea, I assume that I would need to load the get_class_list() on page load using AJAX? How could I store the json response though? Could I store it in a hidden HTML div? But then how would I get it back as a PHP variable?

Comment: The character limit is for the transient name not the data you can store your entire json array as a transient and then load it on demand. You can trigger your API call on wpcf7_init or just init.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a go and update this page with the results.